# Apply a function on one dataframe using another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to calculate distance of the members using node A and node B info provided in the other data frame.
Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

def length(a, b):
    x1 = nodes.loc[a]['x']
    x2 = nodes.loc[b]['x']
    y1 = nodes.loc[a]['y']
    y2 = nodes.loc[b]['y']
    return math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)
```

Here is the node dataframe:

```
node    x    y
1       0    0
2      10   10
3      10   20
```

members dataframe:

```
member  node A   node B
1           1        2
2           2        3
```

I tried this:

```
members['length'] = members.apply(lambda x: length(members['node A'], members['node B']), axis=0)
```

But it says 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported'

expected outcome:

```
member  node A   node B  length
1           1        2    14.14
2           2        3    10
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the expected output, include that in the post.

Comment: I have edited the question how the outcome would look like

Comment: axis should be set to 1 to apply function to each row.https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change multiple things actually as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

def length(a, b):
    x1 = nodes[nodes['node'] == a]['x'].values[0]
    x2 = nodes[nodes['node'] == b]['x'].values[0]

    y1 = nodes[nodes['node'] == a]['y'].values[0]
    y2 = nodes[nodes['node'] == b]['y'].values[0]
    return math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2)


members['length'] = members.apply(lambda x: length(x['node A'], x['node B']), axis=1)
print(members)
#   member  node A  node B     length
#0       1       1       2  14.142136
#1       2       2       3  10.000000
```

Here, I'm going to explain what I have changed:

1. Inside the `length()` function, you need to use the `node` column instead of the index.
2. When applying the `length()` function, you need to apply it on `x` not `members`.
3. Also, the axis of running `length()` on should be `1` ont `0`.

Comment: Thank you! I understood what was the mistake now.

Comment: Glad I could help :)